# PHP $_POST Undefined index Error "Username"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, indexing

I would like to take some data from my html form with a php script in POST, but this script is called in a javascript script and when i try to get the data I have this error : "Undefined index"

Can anoyone help me ? Exscuse me but I've just started learning PHP

part of HTML:

```
<form class="form" id="myform" method="post">
<div class="form__group">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="Username" name="Username" class="form__input" />
</div>
</form>
```

part of JS script:

```
if (errors == false) {
    var Username = document.getElementById("Username");
    var Password = document.getElementById("Password");
    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/register.php",
        success: function () {
            alert('Success');
        }
    });
```

part of PHP script:

```
$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];
```

Comment: Suggest you start by reading the $.ajax documents for setting `data` and `method`

Comment: What is exact error and could not notice password field in your form.

Comment: @charlietfl sorry I couldn’t understand... What should I do?

Comment: You're not specifying which data to send, or through what method it should be sent.

Comment: You have to send the data for `$_POST` to read and you need to set the method as POST. Also suggest studying some ajax/php tutorials

Comment: @Qirel how can I do that ? Can you show me a code example ? Should I add method and data in the $ajax? How can I do that?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the official documentation, as can be found here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You're missing a password field and probably pass your form data to your AJAX-handler (i.e. your PHP script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you better read the doc first http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
var Username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
var Password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "scripts/register.php",
    data: {
        Username: Username,
        Password: Password
    },
    success: function() {
        alert('Success');
    }
});
```

Comment: If he is using jquery, suggest jquery value selectors: `Username: $("#Username").val() , Password: $("#Password").val()`

Comment: @IncredibleHat: yeah, you're right. I got that "mixed style" in my code sometimes, quite messy ;)

Comment: Easy to do especially when migrating TO jquery from older code. I spent a month cleaning a website once. Not fun. So I try to suggest "go full jquery if you got it" =]

Comment: I would actually suggest doing: `data: $('#myform').serialize()` instead of manually fetching each input. That way, you can add an input in your HTML and jQuery will automatically pick it up.

Comment: @IncredibleHat how can I send the entire form and then take the data inside it ? (For example send the form and the take the <input> that it contains

Comment: If someone knows the answer please tell me . Thank all of you for your support